# Can class action lawsuits be filed against game developers that release broken games?

Tags: contract-law, consumer-protection

When game developers release games that are unplayable at launch, are there any applicable laws that protect the consumers that paid for the game?

Most recently, Rockstar Games released **Red Dead Redemption II** on PC and it has been riddled with numerous issues, most of which have [prevented consumers](https://metro.co.uk/2019/11/06/red-dead-redemption-2-suffering-serious-launch-issues-pc-11051184/) [from actually playing](https://www.thesixthaxis.com/2019/11/06/red-dead-redemption-2-pc-launch-review-problems-bugs-issues-fixes/) [the game](https://www.windowscentral.com/red-dead-redemption-2-pc-version-suffering-crashes-bugs-and-failure-start) [they purchased](https://www.engadget.com/2019/11/06/red-dead-redemption-2-pc-launch-problems/).

While that is just one example, we are seeing this happening more and more lately. In most cases, subsequent patches and updates **do** fix the issues eventually, but this is not always true.

So my question is this: are there any legal protections for consumers that purchase a defective digital product? If a game were never patched/fixed to an acceptable point, could a class action lawsuit be filed? How long do developers have to deliver that viable product to the consumer?

Comment: Possibly breach of contract, warranty, consumer protection law.

Answer (score 2):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### Consumers can get a refund

Two of the consumer guarantees under the Australian Consumer Law is that a product must be fit for purpose and of merchantable quality. A piece of software that doesn’t work is clearly neither.